# Counting entries in multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, keyword

I am new to python and currently am looking for a way to count keywords in multiple CSV files. The files have a general structure as follows:

```
PDB ID  NDB ID  Structure Title  Citation Title     Abstract
1ARJ    1ARJ    ARG-bound TAR    Structure of       Solution structure of Arginine  
                RNA              some complex RNA   RNA complex.
```

I would like to get some guidance on how to write a code that imports multiple csv files or loops the input of these files and then returns the value of how many times a keyword came up in a record and which field contained the hit. I have seen some tutorials for the csv import module but I don't know how to use it.

```
import csv
my_list = mRNA


words = {}
for items in my_list:
    for item in items.split(', '):
        words.setdefault(item, 0)
        words[item] += 1

with open('mrna.csv', 'w') as fopen:
    writer = csv.writer(fopen)
    for word, count in words.items():
        writer.writerow([word, count])
```

Comment: I looked up the tutorial on using a csv import module and wrote this blurb.                                                    import csv
my_list = mRNA


words = {}
for items in my_list:
    for item in items.split(', '):
        words.setdefault(item, 0)
        words[item] += 1

with open('mrna.csv', 'w') as fopen:
    writer = csv.writer(fopen)
    for word, count in words.items():
        writer.writerow([word, count])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `mRNA` defined? Maybe you should re-read the [csv module examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) and try to start from the beginning, try and output the data from the CSV file before trying to count the keywords.